# Modificar objeto de ArrayList en un JTable

Tags: java, array, java-swing

Tengo una Tabla y la lleno con objetos de un ArrayList quiero saber como puedo modificar los datos que ya fueron guardados en el ArrayList y que la tabla los presenta

Comment: Hola @David, por favor añade más información a la pregunta porque ahora mismo es un poco general y no está clara: ¿qué quieres actualizar la tabla o el ArrayList?¿Puedes compartir un ejemplo de cómo lo estás haciendo y qué es lo que quieres obtener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes recorrer el ArrayList y actualizar la información de algún elemento que desees.

Con una Lista Cualquiera

```
ArrayList<SomeClass> someList = new ArrayList<SomeClass>();
```

Se recorre la lista buscando un elemento que cumpla con el id del objeto a modificar

```
for (int x=0; x< someList(); x++) {
    item = someList.get(x); // Obtener el elemento en un indice
    if ( item.get_id_attribute == id ){ // Si el id es del objeto buscado
       item.set_attribute = "value"   // Actualizar un atributo usando un metodo accesos para modificar la información 
    }
}
```